# Coloring the QString

Tags: qt, qt4

```
  QString text("<FONT COLOR=red>%1</FONT>");
        text.arg(strMat);
QDomNode text_node
text_node.setNodeValue(text);
```

I have the above code . What i want is text color shall be red and that text value shall be decided during the run time .

Comment: Where are you displaying the string?

Answer (score 1):

QString allows you to store character array and do operations on those character with member functions. Since it is not derived from QWidget it cannot be displayed on its own. You will need a QWidget (like QLabel) to display the string. And then you can set font color of the QLabel to display text in specific color.

You can set the font color(to red) for a label as below

```
label->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);");
```

[Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) might help you to learn about style sheet support in Qt and how to use them

Comment: Also if you need you can store color for each string and that string in a struct.